# In an Ember Component where should you put reusable code that isn't an action?

Tags: ember.js

I have a standard component defined something like:

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  hideIfEmptyChange: function() {

    var thingOfInterest = ...;
    var otherThingOfInterest = ...;

    ...
    // Perform some logic
    ...

    // Perform some logic using thingOfInterest
    // Perform exactly the same logic using otherThingOfInterest
  }.observes('hideIfEmpty.@each')
});
```

I want to move the logic for the last two pieces into their own function to prevent writing out the same code twice just for two different variables.

I *could* write an action on my component and use `this.send('myAction',...)` - but would it be best practice to have this as an action if it isn't going to be used (or even usable) from the component's template? If you shouldn't do it this way then how should you?

My other thought was mixin's - but the code here will be completely specific to the component, so again this doesn't feel 100% right.

**Edit**
The component is used here to observe an array of widgets, which are displayed in a sidebar. To start with the sidebar is hidden away as there are no widgets. When a widget is added the sidebar then slides out using a css3 transition between a bootstrap class I added (col-md-0) and something like col-md-2, at the same time the main column shrinks from something like col-md-10 to col-md-8. Because of the nature of it coming out from zero width the widgets inside squish around during the animation and so need to be hidden during it. So the generic piece of code will be:

```
function(element, classes) {
  var lowWidth = 50;

  // Transition looks awful if columns start from small width, so hide inner content until css3 transition complete if starting from low width
  if ($(element).width() < lowWidth) {
    $('div', element).hide();
    $(element).toggleClass(classes);
    $(element).on('transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd', function(e) {
      $('div', element).fadeIn(250);

      $(this).off(e);
    });
  }
  else {
    $(element).toggleClass(classes);
  }
}
```

My component here is in block form and actually has the sidebar within it in the template.

```
{{#hideable-cols hideIfEmpty=rightSidebarWidgets leftId="det-main" leftMinClass="col-md-8" leftMaxClass="col-md-10" rightId="det-sidebar-right" rightMinClass="col-md-0" rightMaxClass="col-md-2"}}
  <div id="det-main" class="col-md-10 resizes">
    {{outlet}}
  </div>
  <div id="det-sidebar-right" class="det-sidebar resizes col-md-0">
    {{widget-area widgets=rightSidebarWidgets saveObjectFromWidget="saveObjectFromWidget" removeWidget="removeRightWidget"}}
  </div>
{{/hideable-cols}}
```

The only other way to do what I wanted would have been if I could have set 'inner' components to only be able to react to changes in the array of widgets AFTER the parent block component is happy/done. I've used something similar in knockout js but couldn't see this kind of feature in Ember, so my workaround was to hide the div where the widgets are added, do the transition and show the div again afterward.

Comment: `mixins/components/hideIfEmpty.js` nothing wrong with it. [Though you owe @stefanpenner 10$ now](https://twitter.com/stefanpenner/status/576510533773303808)

Comment: Can you show us the actual code? You might be going about it the wrong way (code wise).

Comment: Thanks @Kitler, I've edited with some more specific info. Essentially its a component to transition two inner columns between two bootstrap classes depending on if an array is empty or not. If there is a better way, or a way to not use observes would love to know.